# Regd : Closing app programatically through Android application

Tags: android

I want to close Android application programatically through code.I have 2 activities.First MainScreen & the Second Screen.

I tried the code

```
System.exit();
finishAffinity();
finishAndRemoveTask();
```

Problem is this its getting me to the HomeScreen

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172367/what-will-happen-when-system-exit0-execute

Comment: you cannot close your application . It is handle by OS. But you can make FirstActivity noHistory="true" and in SecondActivity simply call finish();

Comment: Explain your problem a little bit more. After closing all your activity where you wanna go.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts...

Answer (score 1):

Try with this,

System.exit(0);

this.finishAffinity(); this option is for above api 16

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using

```
`android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`
```

in your onDestroy() of Main activity.
For reference go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/how-to-exit-from-the-application-and-show-the-home-screen)